# not understood working js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Muj3d/8/

suppose mouse cursor is on `div_1`, now drag mouse from `div_1` to `div_2`, as we see, first time happened action `mouseout` and after `mouseover`. Ok, now remove `alerts()` from js code and repeat mouse drag again, as we see, `div_2` not removed, question: why?

Comment: Because on `mouseover` event of div2, you are again displaying it as `block`.

Comment: You'll see differences because the alert will cause `mouseout` events as well. If you want to test with the correct events, you're better off having a "status" type element that can show you want you need to see

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed Yes, but before displaying it as block, must be working `mouseout` which must removes `div_2` ?

Comment: actually alerts moves your cursor focus from div's to browser window (alert dialog is part of browser). That's why you have different effects. Use console.log() if using firefox firebug to test/debug your code

Answer (score 1):

Because on `mouseover` event of div2, you are again displaying it as `block`. `alert` seems to introduce a delay. Try moving mouse from `div_1` to some other place in the document, rather than moving it to `div_2`, see that `div_2` vanishes, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Because the two events are firing "almost" at the same time. I say almost meaning that the `mouseover` fires after the `mouseout`, leaving the div showing (`display: block`).

If you log the events rather than alerting you will see them both firing in that order: http://jsfiddle.net/Muj3d/14/

Hope that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions are hiding and then showing the div. Without the pause in execution that the alert provides this happens so quickly that you don't notice it.

Remove the following:

```
   $("#div_2").css({
       display: "block"
   });
```

And you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```
$("#div_1").on("mouseout", function () {

      $("#div_2").css({
        'display': "none"
       });
     });


   $("#div_1").on("mouseover", function () {
      $("#div_2").css({
         'display': "block"
        });
   });
```

**use quotes with css display property.**

Answer (score 0):

Just change the second event sender from `#div_2` to `#div_1`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                $("#div_1").on("mouseout", function () {
                      //alert("action mouseout");
                    $("#div_2").css({display: "none"});
                 });


                  $("#div_1").on("mouseover", function () {
                       //alert("action mouseover");
                      $("#div_2").css({display: "block"});
                 });
            });​
```